# What Font Does the ToggleSwitch Use

Tags: windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I'm just trying to figure out the ToggleSwitch font that comes with the WPtoolkit, so that I may apply a similar style to other items in my app. How may I determine this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPToolkit uses the default Windows Phone resources for fonts/colours.

For the exact styles you can look at the `Generic.xaml` theme in the [`WPTookit` source](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Themes/Generic.xaml)

In this case it's using `PhoneFontFamilyNormal`, `FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"`

For a full list of Resources for WP take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx)